# How to run a JS script in an unfocused tab?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I have a chrome extension which automatically turns off the microphone and camera, and joins the meeting when a google meet joining page is open.

The extension works perfectly when the meet tab is in focus. However when a different tab is in focus, the auto-join feature works but the script fails to turn off the microphone and camera.

The same thing occurs when I use TamperMonkey to run this script.

This issue is a problem because I have a PHP script running on a website which redirects to the google meet at a particular time. So the tab is often not in focus when the redirect happens.

How can I get this script to work even when the meet tab is out of focus?

**manifest.json (chrome extension manifest file):**

```
{
    "name": "automatic class joiner",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "automatic class joiner"
    }
}
```

**content.js (chrome extension code):**

```
function start() {
    url = location.href;
    if (url.includes("meet.google.com")) {
        its_meet();
    }
}

function its_meet() {
    items = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    // Turn off camera and microphone
    setTimeout(function() {
        try {
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].hasAttribute("aria-label")) {
                    if (items[i].getAttribute("aria-label")
                        .includes("microphone") ||
                        items[i].getAttribute("aria-label")
                        .includes("camera")) {
                        items[i].click();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }, 5000)
    
    // Join the Meet
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].hasAttribute("jsname")) {
                if (items[i].getAttribute("jsname")
                    .includes("Qx7uuf")) {
                    items[i].click();
                }
            }
        }
    }, 8000);

}
start();
```

**meet.php (website script):**

```
<?php
    /*
        Code to sleep until meet url is available and store it in $url
        ...
        ...
    */   
    header('Location: '.$url);
?>
```

My knowledge of JS and PHP is abysmal. I am open to alternative ways to solve this problem.

I have tried some chrome webstore extensions which automatically turn off the camera and microphone and join the meet. But they also don't work properly when the meet tab is not in focus.